# Fast formula for a "high contrast" curve

Tags: optimization, math, formula

My inner loop contains a calculation that profiling shows to be problematic.

The idea is to take a greyscale pixel x (0 <= x <= 1), and "increase its contrast". My requirements are fairly loose, just the following:

- for x < .5, 0 <= f(x) < x
- for x > .5, x < f(x) <= 1
- f(0) = 0
- f(x) = 1 - f(1 - x), i.e. it should be "symmetric"
- Preferably, the function should be smooth.

So the graph must look something like this:

[image: Graph].

I have two implementations (their results differ but both are conformant):

```
float cosContrastize(float i) {
    return .5 - cos(x * pi) / 2;
}

float mulContrastize(float i) {
    if (i < .5) return i * i * 2;
    i = 1 - i;
    return 1 - i * i * 2;
}
```

So I request either a microoptimization for one of these implementations, or an original, faster formula of your own.

Maybe one of you can even twiddle the bits ;)

Comment: Perhaps we could help you better if you can tell us what language you are using (I assume Java) and what is the compiler/runtime involved.

Comment: C# with a MS compiler and runtime, but I'm willing to rewrite the critical algo in C++ if I find I need to...

Comment: C# with camelCased method names? :(

Comment: Many such functions are faster/simpler when centered around zero. I'm not sure about the rest of your program, but if this kind of code is critical, you might consider repositioning your data-representation to scale from -1..1 rather than 0..1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trivially you could simply threshold, but I imagine this is too dumb:

```
return i < 0.5 ? 0.0 : 1.0;
```

Since you mention 'increasing contrast' I assume the input values are luminance values. If so, and they are discrete (perhaps it's an 8-bit value), you could use a lookup table to do this quite quickly.

Your 'mulContrastize' looks reasonably quick. One optimization would be to use integer math. Let's say, again, your input values could actually be passed as an 8-bit unsigned value in [0..255]. (Again, possibly a fine assumption?) You could do something roughly like...

```
int mulContrastize(int i) {
  if (i < 128) return (i * i) >> 7; 
  // The shift is really: * 2 / 256
  i = 255 - i;
  return 255 - ((i * i) >> 7);
```

Comment: A threshold is too far from smooth to be useful in my case. They are luminance values, yeah. They aren't discrete values - they are actually floats, for two reasons. First, in OpenGL, float textures are fastest. And second, I made the decision to use 0.0-1.0 floats to make my math easy *and* fast. But I never thought of contrastizing with a lookup table, I'll look into that and see if it outweighs the OpenGL texture concern. The implementation you posted is nice indeed, but not as nice as a lookup table. And my mulContrastize is "reasonably quick" indeed, but not in such a tight inner loop :)

Comment: Btw, you shouldn't divide by 255 twice, just once. So you should shift by 7.

Comment: Oops you are right, that normalizes one step too far. Will fix the example.

Comment: ++ for the lookup-table suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using a lookup table. By itself, it did zero improvement. But it allowed me to do several other optimizations - so - thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Consider the following **sigmoid**-shaped functions (properly translated to the desired range):

- [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)
- [normal CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function)
- [tanh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Standard_algebraic_expressions)
- [logit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function)

[image: screenshot]

I generated the above figure using MATLAB. If interested here's the code:

```
x = -3:.01:3;
plot(   x, 2*(x>=0)-1, ...
        x, erf(x), ...
        x, tanh(x), ...
        x, 2*normcdf(x)-1, ...
        x, 2*(1 ./ (1 + exp(-x)))-1, ...
        x, 2*((x-min(x))./range(x))-1  )
legend({'hard' 'erf' 'tanh' 'normcdf' 'logit' 'linear'})
```

Comment: The OP's main issue is speed.  How do these speed things up?

Comment: Thanks, at least I know they're called 'sigmoid' now ;) I did an easy implementation with tanh, it's as fast as the cos one. The rest will take quite a bit more thought and I think they'll be slower but we'll see.

Comment: ++ Nice. Personally, I lean toward logit (actually it's the inverse logit function), because you only have to call exp() once, and a division. You can make it sharper by scaling X.

Comment: @tom10, the OP can see the formulas used, an consider which suites best.

Answer (score 4):

A piecewise interpolation can be fast and flexible.  It requires only a few decisions followed by a multiplication and addition, and can approximate any curve.  It also avoids the courseness that can be introduced by lookup tables (or the additional cost in two lookups followed by an interpolation to smooth this out), though the lut might work perfectly fine for your case.

[image]

With just a few segments, you can get a pretty good match.  Here there will be courseness in the color *gradients*, which will be much harder to detect than courseness in the absolute colors.

As Eamon Nerbonne points out in the comments, segmentation can be optimized by "choos[ing] your segmentation points based on something like the second derivative to maximize detail", that is, where the slope is changing the most.  Clearly, in my posted example, having three segments in the middle of the five segment case doesn't add much more detail.

Comment: And if you're really being snazzy, you can choose your segmentation points based on something like the second derivative to maximize detail (no point in differentiating segments in the central, fairly straight segment).

Comment: @Eamon: Thanks for the second derivative idea. I knew I was being lazy with the center points, but I really like the generalization to the second derivative.