# How to convert the output of an artificial neural network into probabilities?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I've read about neural network a little while ago and I understand how an ANN (especially a multilayer perceptron that learns via backpropagation) can learn to classify an event as true or false.

I think there are two ways :

1) You get one output neuron. It it's value is > 0.5 the events is likely true, if it's value is <=0.5 the event is likely to be false.

2) You get two output neurons, if the value of the first is > than the value of the second the event is likely true and vice versa.

In these case, the ANN tells you if an event is likely true or likely false. It does not tell how likely it is.

Is there a way to convert this value to some odds or to directly get odds out of the ANN. I'd like to get an output like "The event has a 84% probability to be true"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Once a NN has been trained, for eg. using backprogation as mentioned in the question (whereby the backprogation logic has "nudged" the weights in ways that minimize the error function) the weights associated with all individual inputs ("outside" inputs or intra-NN inputs) are fixed.  The NN can then be used for classifying purposes.

Whereby the math (and the "options") during the learning phase can get a bit thick, it is relatively simple and straightfoward when operating as a classifier.  The main algorithm is to compute an activation value for each neuron, as the sum of the input x weight for that neuron.   This value is then fed to an activation function which purpose's is to normalize it and convert it to a boolean (in typical cases, as some networks do not have an all-or-nothing rule for some of their layers).  The activation function can be more complex than you indicated, in particular it needn't be linear, but whatever its shape, typically sigmoid, it operate in the same fashion: figuring out where the activation fits on the curve, and if applicable, above or below a threshold.  The basic algorithm then processes all neurons at a given layer before proceeding to the next.

With this in mind, the question of using the perceptron's ability to qualify its guess (or indeed guesses - plural) with a percentage value, finds an easy answer: you bet it can, its output(s) is real-valued (if anything in need of normalizing) before we convert it to a discrete value (a boolean or a category ID in the case of several categories), using the activation functions and the threshold/comparison methods described in the question.

So... How and Where do I get "my percentages"?...  All depends on the NN implementation, and more importantly, the implementation dictates the type of normalization functions that can be used to bring activation values in the 0-1 range *and* in a fashion that the sum of all percentages "add up" to 1.  In its simplest form, the activation function can be used to normalize the value and the weights of the input to the output layer can be used as factors to ensure the "add up" to 1 question (provided that these weights are indeed so normalized themselves).

Et voilà!

**Claritication**: (following Mathieu's note)
One doesn't need to change anything in the way the Neural Network itself works; the only thing needed is to somehow "hook into" the logic of *output* neurons to access the [real-valued] activation value they computed, or, possibly better, to access the real-valued output of the activation function, *prior its boolean conversion* (which is typically based on a threshold value or on some stochastic function).

In other words, the NN works as previously, neither its training nor recognition logic are altered, the inputs to the NN stay the same, as do the connections between various layers etc.  We only get a copy of the real-valued activation of the neurons in the output layer, and we use this to compute a percentage.  The actual formula for the percentage calculation depends on the nature of the activation value and its associated function (its scale, its range relative to other neurons' output etc.).
Here are a few simple cases (taken from the question's suggested output rules)
1) If there is a single output neuron: the ratio of the value provided by the activation function relative to the range of that function should do.
2) If there are two (or more output neurons), as with classifiers for example:  If all output neurons have the same activation function, the percentage for a given neuron is that of its activation function value divided by the sum of all activation function values.  If the activation functions vary, it becomes a case by case situation because the distinct activation functions may be indicative of a purposeful desire to give more weight to some of the neurons, and the percentage should respect this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this answer, I'm not sure I understand correctly. What you say is you just threat the output of the ANN as probability and simply make sure that the probabilities adds up to one? How will the ANN learn that what it should output is probabilities. When I train it, I do train it with real result, so every output value in the training set are 0 or 1 (0.05 or 0.95). However when I use the ANN for real work, I'd like an output value of 0.7 means that the event is true (1) with a probability of 70%.

Are you telling me I don't need to do anything special to get this kind of output?

Comment: @Mathieu See "clarification". I hope it effectively clarifies things, I sometimes make matters more confusing in my attempt to do the contrary ;-)   I think in a nutshell it is only complicated because one needs to know the exact numerical semantics of the real-valued values associated with the outut of a neuron to be in a position to normalize these values properly.  (I have values -plural, because it can either be the activation value or the [real-valued] output of the activation function)

Comment: Hi mjv, you clarifications effectively answer my interogations, thanks for this answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Mathieu.  Merci! And glad I this was a clarification.  Unrelated to the question but maybe of interest to you, I'd like to plug here the HTM concept developed by numenta (www.numenta.com), as this provides a very interesting framework for classifiers.

Comment: Why are those values probabilities?

Comment: @ziggystar In the question and in my answer, the word "Probabilities" is used somewhat loosely. The values in questions would better be named `"Percentage or confidence"` (POC) or something similar. While missing a formal declaration of the _variable they are probabilities of_, these value never the less have all the main characteristics of probabilities, in particular their 0 to 1 range, the fact that they sum to 1  (the POC this is category A plus the POC this is category B plus... the POCs of all other categories, amounts to 1.), and also the fact that POC(not X) = 1 - POC(X).

Comment: @mjv Properties 1 and 2 can easily be achieved through normalization. But what makes you so sure that the third property holds? How would you define the negation via the ANN? How do you define 'not X'?

Comment: How does this work with tanh activation functions, when an output 'probability' can be negative?

Comment: @michel - `tanh(x)` will always return a value in the [-1..1] range, and is often used to normalize the value of a `hidden` layer.  An `output` layer may want to be in the range [0..1], so would use a different normalization function, perhaps the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function .

Answer (score 18):

What you can do is to use a [sigmoid transfer function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoids) on the output layer nodes (that accepts data ranges (-inf,inf) and outputs a value in [-1,1]).
Then by using the **1-of-n output encoding** (one node for each class), you can map the range [-1,1] to [0,1] and use it as probability for each class value (note that this works naturally for more than just two classes).

Comment: Your output range for the sigmoid is wrong. The output of the sigmoid transfer function is a value in [0,1]. It is shown in the link you provided.

Comment: @FabriceDugas sigmoid often refers to a family of functions, with output range either [0,1] or [-1,1] depending on convention. See this for examples: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1480075/97160

Comment: Ahh my bad. Conventions conventions. Thank you for the example!

Answer (score 10):

The activation value of a single output neuron is a linearly weighted sum, and may be directly interpreted as an approximate probability if the network is trained to give outputs a range from 0 to 1.  This would tend to be the case if the transfer function (or output function) in both the preceding stage and providing the final output is in the 0 to 1 range too (typically the sigmoidal logistic function). However, there is no guarantee that it will but repairs are possible.  Moreover unless the sigmoids are logistic and the weights are constrained to be positive and sum to 1, it is unlikely.  Generally a neural network will train in a more balanced way using the tanh sigmoid and weights and activations that range positive and negative (due to the symmetry of this model).  Another factor is the prevalence of the class - if it is 50% then a 0.5 threshold is likely to be effective for logistic and a 0.0 threshold for tanh.  The sigmoid is designed to push things towards the centre of the range (on backpropogation) and constrain it from going out of the range (in feedforward). The significance of the performance (with respect to the Bernoulli distribution) can also be interpreted as a probability that the neuron is making real predictions rather than guessing.  Ideally the bias of the predictor to positives should match the prevalence of positives in the real world (which may vary at different times and places, e.g. bull vs bear markets, e.g. credit worthiness of people applying for loans vs people who fail to make loan payments) - calibrating to probabilities has the advantage that any desired bias can be set easily.

If you have two neurons for two classes, each can be interpreted independently as above, and the halved difference between them can also be.  It is like flipping the negative class neuron and averaging.  The differences can also give rise to a probability of significance estimate (using the T-test).

The Brier score and its Murphy decomposition give a more direct estimate of the probability that an average answer is correct, while Informedness gives the probability the classifier is making an informed decision rather than a guess, ROC AUC gives the probability a positive class will be ranked higher than a negative class (by a positive predictor), and Kappa will give a similar number that matches Informedness when prevalence = bias.

What you normally want is both a significance probability for the overall classifier (to ensure that you are playing on a real field, and not in an imaginary framework of guestimates) and a probability estimate for a specific example.  There are various ways to calibrate, including doing a regression (linear or nonlinear) versus probability and using its inverse function to remap to a more accurate probability estimate.  This can be seen by the Brier score improving, with the calibration component reducing towards 0, but the discrimination component remaining the same, as should ROC AUC and Informedness (Kappa is subject to bias and may worsen).

A simple non-linear way to calibrate to probabilities is to use the ROC curve - as the threshold changes for the output of a single neuron or the difference between two competing neurons, we plot the results true and false positive rates on a ROC curve (the false and true negative rates are naturally the complements, as what isn't really a positive is a negative).  Then you scan the ROC curve (polyline) point by point (each time the gradient changes) sample by sample and the proportion of positive samples gives you a probability estimate for positives corresponding to the neural threshold that produced that point.  Values between points on the curve can be linearly interpolated between those that are represented in the calibration set - and in fact any bad points in the ROC curve, represented by deconvexities (dents) can be smoothed over by the convex hull - probabilistically interpolating between the endpoints of the hull segment.  Flach and Wu propose a technique that actually flips the segment, but this depends on information being used the wrong way round and although it could be used repeatedly for arbitrary improvement on the calibration set, it will be increasingly unlikely to generalize to a test situation.

(I came here looking for papers I'd seen ages ago on these ROC-based approaches - so this is from memory and without these lost references.)

Answer (score 10):

I will be very prudent in interpreting  the outputs of a neural networks (in fact any machine learning classifier) as a probability. The machine is trained to discriminate between classes, not to estimate the probability density. In fact, we don't have this information in the data, we have to infer it. For my experience I din't advice anyone to interpret directly the outputs as probabilities.

Answer (score 7):

did you try prof. Hinton's suggestion of training the network with softmax activation function and cross entropy error?

as an example create a three layer network with the following:

```
linear neurons   [ number of features ]
sigmoid neurons [ 3 x number of features ]
linear neurons   [ number of classes ]
```

then train them with cross entropy error softmax transfer with your favourite optimizer stochastic descent/iprop plus/ grad descent. After training the output neurons should be normalized to sum of 1.

Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_activation_function for details. Shark Machine Learning framework does provide Softmax feature through combining two models. And prof. Hinton  an excellent online course @ http://coursera.com regarding the details.

Comment: Honestly after 4? years of deliberation: have no proper recollection. Nor do I think anymore that computing the posterior probability of an NN is that simple. You're 'probably' :) right. In fact to compute the probability of an NN I would suggest Bishop as a reading, and bayesian treatment.

Answer (score 4):

I can  remember I saw an example of Neural network trained with back propagation to approximate  the probability of an outcome in the book Introduction to the theory of neural computation (hertz krogh palmer). I think the key to the example was a special learning rule so that you didn't have to convert the output of a unit to probability, but instead you got automatically the probability as output.
If you have the opportunity, try to check that book.

(by the way, "boltzman machines", although less famous, are neural networks designed specifically to learn probability distributions, you may want to check them as well)

Answer (score 4):

When using ANN for 2-class classification and logistic sigmoid activation function is used in the output layer, the output values could be interpreted as probabilities.

So if you choosing between 2 classes, you train using 1-of-C encoding, where 2 ANN outputs will have training values (1,0) and (0,1) for each of classes respectively.

To get probability of first class in percent, just multiply first ANN output to 100. To get probability of other class use the second output.

This could be generalized for multi-class classification using softmax activation function.

You can read more, including proofs of probabilistic interpretation here:

[1] Bishop, Christopher M. Neural networks for pattern recognition. Oxford university press, 1995.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not exactly the same problem, but for me, who had a classification problem with multiple classes, this video helped a ton (and its really simple to understand):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SFsc2P240rw&ab_channel=KapilSachdeva

In a nutshell, you make the output positive through exponentiation. To do this, you simply call np.exp().
Then, you normalize the outputs, so that the sum of all values adds up to 1.
This can be by dividing the exponentiated output by the sum of the exponentiated output.

So, step 1:

```
exponentiated_output = np.exp(output)
```

Step 2:

```
probabilistic_output = exponentiated_output / np.sum(exponentiated_output, axis=0)
```

Now, the output adds up to 1, is positive and the values are between 0 and 1. Therefore, the requirements for probability distribution is satisfied.

In the video, he also explains temperature scaling, so that the probabilities differentiate less. Hope that helps.