# Interpreting Neural Network output

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

For a classification problem, how is the output of the network usually determined?

Say, there are three possible classes, each with a numerical identifier, would a reasonable solution be to sum the outputs and take that sum as the overall output of the network? Or would you take the average of the networks outputs?

There is plenty of information regarding ANN theory, but not much about application, but I apoligise if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a multi-layer perceptron classifier with 3 classes, one typically constructs a network with 3 outputs and trains the network so that (1,0,0) is the target output for the first class, (0,1,0) for the second class, and (0,0,1) for the third class.  For classifying a new observation, you typically select the output with the greatest value (e.g., (0.12, 0.56, 0.87) would be classified as class 3).

Comment: Thanks for the response. What exactly do you mean by a new observation?  Thank you.

Comment: For clarity sake, would other methods work, such as those mentioned in my first post?

Comment: If you are asking is it reasonable to take the sum or average of the outputs, then no, I don't think that is a viable approach to classification.  The point of classification is to choose *between* the various classes (i.e., pick one of the three classes).  If you sum or average the values of the three output nodes, then you are losing the ability to discriminate between the three classes.  That said, there may still be useful information in the sum or average (e.g., a value close to 3 suggests a higher probability of misclassification).

Comment: Lovely, thanks. I am now working with a representation similar to your suggestion.

Comment: do you mean by greatest value, the greatest value in it's magnitude(i.e after taking the absolute value) ? if we have the output [-.2 .5 -1] which class will be decide to classify the input to?

Comment: My answer assumed a logistic sigmoid activation function, which is constrained the the range (0, 1), so there would be no negative values and you would just choose the highest value. If you were instead using something like the hyperbolic tangent, which has the range (-1, 1), you would still choose the largest value (not absolute value) because negative values are on the wrong side of the decision boundary.

Answer (score 0):

I agree mostly with bogatron and further you will find many posts here advising on this kind of "multi-class classification" with neural networks.

Regarding your heading I would like to add that you can interpret that output as a probability since I struggled to find theoretical foundation for this. Going on I'll talk about a neural network with 3 neurons in the output layer, indicating 1 for the respective class.
Since the sum of all three outputs will always be 1 in training, the neural network will also give feed-forward output with a sum of one (so rather (0.12 0.36 0.52) than bogatrons example)) Then you can interpret these figures as the probability that the respective input belongs to class 1/2/3 (probability is 0.52 that it belongs to class 3)).

This is true when using the logistic function or the tanh as activation functions.

More on this: 
Posterior probability via neural networks: http://www-vis.lbl.gov/~romano/mlgroup/papers/neural-networks-survey.pdf
[How to convert the output of an artificial neural network into probabilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523420/how-to-convert-the-output-of-an-artificial-neural-network-into-probabilities)

Comment: Just to clarify regarding the example outputs I used - In general, the network outputs will not sum to one unless there is a normalization performed in the output layer (I didn't make that assumption).  If they are normalized, then as you stated, the outputs can be interpreted as probabilities.  Regarding @VisionIncision's question regarding the sum/mean of the outputs, if the outputs are normalized, the sum and mean will have no significance (the sum will always be 1 and the mean will always be 1/3).

Comment: The normalization thing makes sense as well but somewhere I got this idea that it is inherent in a trained neural network, as in the ANN is learning that the sum of always 1 [0,0,1] / [1,0,0] etc. On the other hand, why should a NN _not_ learn that the sum of outputs is always 1?

Comment: You typically train the network with the *goal* of the training to have all zeros and a single unity output (corresponding to the correct class) but error can't always be reduced to zero (and even if it could , you don't always want it to because you may overfit your solution).  Recall also that the logistic function (a.k.a. sigmoid) only has an output of 0 or 1 at negative and positive infinity, which we will never see in practice.

Comment: What I mean is just that the very likely outputs are those which sum up to one, since ALL observations do so as well. Example: [0.12 0.36 0.52]. Obviously the error is not zero and the output not close to 0/1 at any output. But as all observations have outputs summing up to one, the net will recognize that. As well as it recognizes the sole frequency of let's say class 3 versus the others. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean but the problem is that in many real situations, the classes are not perfectly separable, either due to their distribution within the input feature space or due to the ANN architecture (number of layers and nodes). In those situations, there should be no expectation that the outputs will sum close to unity (unless they are explicitly normalized).