# Getting a neural network to output anything inbetween -1.0 and 1.0

Tags: c#, neural-network

I am trying to make a back propagation neural network.
Based upon the the tutorials i found here : [MSDN article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/04/01/back-propagation-using-c.aspx) by James McCaffrey. He gives many examples but all his networks are based upon the same problem to solve. So his networks look like 4:7:3 >>  4input - 7hidden - 3output.

His output is always binary 0 or 1, one output gets a 1, to classify an Irish flower, into one of the three categories.

I would like to solve another problem with a neural network and that would require me 2 neural networks where one needs an output inbetween 0..255 and another inbetween 0 and 2times Pi. (a full turn, circle). Well essentially i think i need an output that range from 0.0 to 1.0 or from -1 to 1 and anything in between, so that i can multiply it to becomme 0..255 or 0..2Pi

I think his network does behave, like it does because of his computeOutputs 
Which I show below here :

```
  private double[] ComputeOutputs(double[] xValues)
    {

    if (xValues.Length != numInput)
            throw new Exception("Bad xValues array length");

        double[] hSums = new double[numHidden]; // hidden nodes sums scratch array
        double[] oSums = new double[numOutput]; // output nodes sums

        for (int i = 0; i < xValues.Length; ++i) // copy x-values to inputs
            this.inputs[i] = xValues[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < numHidden; ++j)  // compute i-h sum of weights * inputs
            for (int i = 0; i < numInput; ++i)
                hSums[j] += this.inputs[i] * this.ihWeights[i][j]; // note +=

        for (int i = 0; i < numHidden; ++i)  // add biases to input-to-hidden sums
            hSums[i] += this.hBiases[i];

        for (int i = 0; i < numHidden; ++i)   // apply activation
            this.hOutputs[i] = HyperTanFunction(hSums[i]); // hard-coded

        for (int j = 0; j < numOutput; ++j)   // compute h-o sum of weights * hOutputs
            for (int i = 0; i < numHidden; ++i)
                oSums[j] += hOutputs[i] * hoWeights[i][j];

        for (int i = 0; i < numOutput; ++i)  // add biases to input-to-hidden sums
            oSums[i] += oBiases[i];

        double[] softOut = Softmax(oSums); // softmax activation does all outputs at once for efficiency
        Array.Copy(softOut, outputs, softOut.Length);

        double[] retResult = new double[numOutput]; // could define a GetOutputs method instead
        Array.Copy(this.outputs, retResult, retResult.Length);
        return retResult;
```

The network uses the folowing hyperTan function

```
      private static double HyperTanFunction(double x)
      {
        if (x < -20.0) return -1.0; // approximation is correct to 30 decimals
        else if (x > 20.0) return 1.0;
        else return Math.Tanh(x);
      }
```

In above a function makes for the output layer use of Softmax() and it is i think critical to problem here. In that I think it makes his output all binary, and it looks like this :

```
     private static double[] Softmax(double[] oSums)
    {
        // determine max output sum
        // does all output nodes at once so scale doesn't have to be re-computed each time
        double max = oSums[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < oSums.Length; ++i)
            if (oSums[i] > max) max = oSums[i];

        // determine scaling factor -- sum of exp(each val - max)
        double scale = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < oSums.Length; ++i)
            scale += Math.Exp(oSums[i] - max);

        double[] result = new double[oSums.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < oSums.Length; ++i)
            result[i] = Math.Exp(oSums[i] - max) / scale;

        return result; // now scaled so that xi sum to 1.0
    }
```

How to rewrite softmax ? 
So the network will be able to give non binary answers ?

Notice the full code of the network is [here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/~/media/ECG/visualstudiomagazine/Code%20Download/2015/04/0415vsm_McCaffrey.zip). if you would like to try it out.

Also as to test the network the following accuracy function is used, maybe the binary behaviour emerges from it

```
public double Accuracy(double[][] testData)
    {
        // percentage correct using winner-takes all
        int numCorrect = 0;
        int numWrong = 0;
        double[] xValues = new double[numInput]; // inputs
        double[] tValues = new double[numOutput]; // targets
        double[] yValues; // computed Y

        for (int i = 0; i < testData.Length; ++i)
        {
            Array.Copy(testData[i], xValues, numInput); // parse test data into x-values and t-values
            Array.Copy(testData[i], numInput, tValues, 0, numOutput);
            yValues = this.ComputeOutputs(xValues);
            int maxIndex = MaxIndex(yValues); // which cell in yValues has largest value?
            int tMaxIndex = MaxIndex(tValues);
            if (maxIndex == tMaxIndex)
                ++numCorrect;
            else
                ++numWrong;
        }
        return (numCorrect * 1.0) / (double)testData.Length;
}
```

Comment: This is way too broad and high-level for SO. You need to ask this in a Computer Science forum.

Comment: i think you need to use kohonen'n network for your problem http://home.agh.edu.pl/~vlsi/AI/koho_t/index_eng.html

Comment: My Neural Network knowledge is a bit rusty, but I just tried your code (as best as I could work out) and I am not getting binary values out:
`Results: 0.28 0.29 0.43`.  I don't think the problem lies with the Softmax function.

Comment: @Enigmativity I disagree - SO has a neural-network tag with 3.5k followers.  This question has research and shows what the OP has tried already.  The question is not too broad - it is a "what have I done wrong" question which is fine for SO.

Comment: Softmax is a common way of converting the output to a probability, the result will always be an array of probabilities (between 0 and 1) that sums to 1. In a classification problem, it represents the probability that the image is in that class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case that someone gets into the same situation.
If you need some example code of a  neural network regression
(a NNR)  That's how they are called.

Here is link to sample [code](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/7/9/D79BBA79-4776-4A08-B339-B775F6F86EB7/Code_McCaffrey.TestRun.0316.zip) in C#, and here is [a good article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt683800.aspx) about it. Notice the guy writes more articles there, you wont find everything but there's a lot there. Despite I was following this man for a while I missed this specific article as I didn't know how they where called, when I asked the question here on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit rusty at Neural Netowrks but I think, if you want to have a range of values from your output then you need to make sure your activation functions on your output layer are linear (or something that has a similar effect).

Try adding this method:

```
private static double[] Linear(double[] oSums)
{
    double sum = oSums.Sum(d => Math.Abs(d));

    double[] result = new double[oSums.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < oSums.Length; ++i)
        result[i] = Math.Abs(oSums[i]) / sum;

    // scaled so that xi sum to 1.0
    return result;
}
```

And then in the `ComputeOutputs` method you need to use this new activation function for the output (rather than Softmax):

```
...
//double[] softOut = Softmax(oSums); // all outputs at once for efficiency
double[] softOut = Linear(oSums); // all outputs at once for efficiency
Array.Copy(softOut, outputs, softOut.Length);
...
```

This should now output linear values.

Comment: I updated the question to also show the hyper tanH function.
I read you code try to understand why that network (see download url in question) does only out output binary values.

Could it be caused by the line `int maxIndex = MaxIndex(yValues); // which cell in yValues has largest value?` in the accuracy function then ?
 (you can download the code, but i will also provide that function in the question as well.

Comment: @user3800527 looking into this further - I think that standard neural networks are designed to output binary values.  If you haven't seen it already then the answers to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1523420/340045) are quite interesting.  I think the answer comes down to changing the activation functions on the nodes in the output layer.

Comment: @user3800527 check out [this post also](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/218542).  It seems that while SoftMax might be a good choice for classification, a linear function would be better for you (but only for the output layer).

Comment: @user3800527 I have edited my answer to show you how I added a linear activation function to your code.

Comment: I cannt wait to test it out, but i need some free time at home to test it.
From how i understand, you do understand my problem, so allready lots of thanks, i hope to code it within a few days, (but family takes time too).

Comment: Sorry it took a while to test, i did test it and it doesnt seam to work ?; i'm not realy sure though about it. I made a test data set of RGB colors to let the neural net convert it into HSL, with layers 3:11:3 the scoring didnt go beyond 60%.. Or is that a too complex task maybe?.

Comment: @user3800527 my linear function above was a bit of a guess.  I am not sure if I should have used the Math.Abs() calls but I was trying to get the output to sum to 1.  I am also not sure if the teaching mechanism (back-propagation) works the same for nodes with a linear activation function.  You might want to check these things.  I only wanted to point you in the right direction (e.g. using a linear activation function) in order to get a variable output (rather than a binary output).

Comment: Ben i've dived a bit deeper too, it might be that such networks, can have only a single output neuron. As for your other comment i dont know. I think i need to think of a different test/train for it. But still i need to have a linear answer instead of binary;

Comment: Well i found an answer.. in using another neural network, i found a regresion example and it worked. Also in general it seams they usually have 1 output only so my HSL test wasnt good either.

Comment: I also have a task to understand this code myself, so good timing. As far as i can tell Softmax alone is not enough because there are assumptions made in the rest of the code that bases from the fact that softmax will return a sum no more than 1.  So other areas do 1 - () for example from this assumption.

Comment: @cineammispelt i just posted the answer, should have done that earlier but i was quite bussy at work. Notice also that NNR's usually have 1 output.